# How to remove Background in multiple and make it white in just one click or automate

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background, image-editing, background-removal

I have more than 40 pictures of which I want to remove background and make them white background. I cannot do it one by one as its gonna take a lot of time even days. I want to automate the process is. Kindly help me if there is any possible way to do this.

Comment: There are online services that do very good background removal. Most of them give you a few test shots to try out their algorithm for suitability before you commit to their pricing. Most of them can batch too. Most of them are surprisingly good these days, better than a human without an hour to spare.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Photoshop CC 2021 has a new one-click Remove Background feature. It's not quite as good as preparing your own mask manually, but it seems to do a fairly decent job.

To use it:

1. Open an image, and click on the Background lock icon in the layers panel to convert the image to a normal layer. Also note, the following procedure won't work on a Smart Object, you'd need to rasterize the Smart Object first.
2. Open the Properties panel, and scroll down a bit until you see Quick Actions and the buttons located underneath.
3. Then hit the Remove Background button.

[image]

Comment: I've never used Adobe products. Does that require internet connection to work?

Comment: @OK-Validation - Photoshop doesn't generally require an internet connection on all the time. From time to time however the software needs to connect to the internet to validate the licence. Also for some of the newest AI features, an internet connection is required if you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the website: https://huggingface.co/spaces/gaviego/removebg. I found someone on Reddit who made this online tool using stable diffusion. The website allows batch uploads. I had really good success with removing backgrounds that were mostly white but had shadows in the background.

You can also try Adobe Express Remove Background tool: https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/image/remove-background

But this does not allow batch upload at the moment.